# Исключить некоторые элементы массива при нахождении минимума и максимума

Tags: c#, массивы, консоль

задан массив 7x5, заполненный рандомными числами. Нужно найти минимальный и максимальный элемент, при этом не проверяя некоторые элементы (красной рамочкой обвёл те элементы, которые проверять не нужно). Как это реализовать? Пока ищется минимум и максимум только во всём массиве.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] arr = new int[7, 5];

        Random ran = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                arr[i, j] = ran.Next(10, 100);
                Console.Write("{0}\t", arr[i, j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        int min = arr[0, 0];
        Console.WriteLine("Минимальный элемент:");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (min > arr[i, j])
                {
                    min = arr[i, j];
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine( min);
        int max = arr[0, 0];
        Console.WriteLine("Максимальный элемент:");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (max < arr[i, j])
                {
                    max = arr[i, j];
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(max);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (i == 1 && j ==1) continue;` для каждой вашей ячейки

Comment: Спасибо большое! теперь всё работает так, как и должно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int[,] arr = new int[7, 5];
                bool alpha = false;

                Random ran = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                    {
                        arr[i, j] = ran.Next(10, 100);
                        Console.Write("{0}\t", arr[i, j]);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                int min = arr[0, 0];
                Console.WriteLine("Минимальный элемент:");
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        alpha = (i == 1 && j >= 1 && j <= 3) || (i == 2 && j >= 1 && j <= 3) ||
                                (i == 5 && j >= 1 && j <= 4) || (i == 6 && j >= 1 && j <= 4); 
                        if (!alpha)
                            if (min > arr[i, j])
                                 min = arr[i, j];                               
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(min);
                int max = arr[0, 0];
                Console.WriteLine("Максимальный элемент:");
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        alpha = (i == 1 && j >= 1 && j <= 3) || (i == 2 && j >= 1 && j <= 3) ||
                                (i == 5 && j >= 1 && j <= 4) || (i == 6 && j >= 1 && j <= 4); 
                        if (!alpha)            
                            if (max < arr[i, j])                      
                                 max = arr[i, j];
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(max);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
```